# Azure Form Recognizer - Label variable type data - recieve data in list

Tags: azure, azure-form-recognizer

I have number of PDFs that i'm using to train my model while using azure form recognizer. Currently It is fine.  For example in the data below. The values of **Bill to, Ship to, and Order Number ** is being captured. But there can be a variable number of items. How to receive each item value in a list?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you call Form Recognizer's Analyze() API,  FR's Layout service will return the table and its content, you can do post-process to retrieve the list.  Have you tried checking the Layout result?  it's in analyze result Json file's "pageResults" section.

Comment: Yes got it. Thanks Xin Zou. Inside pageResults there is a key with the name "tables".